# Two checkboxes set disabled then checked if another checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have three checkboxes and want to have number 2 and 3 disabled until number one is checked.
Then set all checked. How do I do that.

I tried with

```
    if ($('{namespace}allowplussning').is(':checked')) {

         $('{namespace}#show-exams-on-passed-courses').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

Then i want a method to make them checked.

But it does'nt work. Number two and three don't become checked.

Comment: Why would they become checked from removing the disabled attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" disabled="true"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" disabled="disable"/>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#check1").click(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $("#check2").removeAttr("disabled").prop('checked', true);;
            $("#check3").removeAttr("disabled").prop('checked', true);;
        }
        else{
           $("#check2").prop("disabled","true").prop('checked', false);;
            $("#check3").prop("disabled","true").prop('checked', false);;
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SxYWG/)

Comment: One thing that doesn't work is that if you want to save the state after doing unchecked the 2 checkboxes still show checked.

Answer (score 0):

As required:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id='cb1' value="Bike" onclick='update()'>I have a bike<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id='cb2' value="Cycle" disabled>I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id='cb3' value="Car" disabled>I have a car 
<script>
  function update() {
    if($('#cb1').is(':checked') ) {
        $( "#cb2" ).prop( "checked", true );
        $( "#cb3" ).prop( "checked", true );
        $( "#cb2" ).attr( "disabled", null );
        $( "#cb3" ).attr( "disabled", null );
        return;
    }
    $( "#cb2" ).prop( "checked", false );
    $( "#cb3" ).prop( "checked", false );
    $( "#cb2" ).attr( "disabled", true );
    $( "#cb3" ).attr( "disabled", true );
 }   
</script>
```

[**Working demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/NNuRT/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this function and call on checkbox click:

```
function updateState() {
    console.log("here");
    if ($('#cb1').is(':checked')) {
        $("#cb2").prop("checked", true);
        $("#cb3").prop("checked", true);
        $("#cb2").removeAttr("disabled", null);
        $("#cb3").removeAttr("disabled", null);
    } else {
        $("#cb2").prop("checked", false);
        $("#cb3").prop("checked", false);
        $("#cb2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#cb3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id='cb1' value="Bike" onclick='updateState()'>I have a bike
```

[Here is jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NNuRT/2/)